# Pandas dataframe conditional mean based on column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

It will be the easiest to explain starting with a sample of the dataframe:

```
    TimeStamp   382.098     382.461     383.185     383.548
    10:28:00    0.012448    0.012362    0.0124485   0.012362
    10:30:00    0.0124135   0.0123965   0.0124135   0.012431
    10:32:00    0.0551035   0.0551725   0.055931    0.0563105
    10:34:00    0.055586    0.0557245   0.056655    0.0569485
    10:36:00    0.055586    0.055776    0.0568105   0.057362
```

I want my output to be:

```
    TimeStamp   382         383
    10:28:00    0.012405    0.01240525
    10:30:00    0.012405    0.01242225
    10:32:00    0.05513     0.05612075
    10:34:00    0.05565525  0.05680175
    10:36:00    0.055681    0.05708625
```

So, I want to look at the column name values and if they are the same up to whole numbers, I want the output col to have the mean of the values for each time index value.

My idea was to use df.round to round the column headers to the nearest whole number and then to use .mean() to somehow apply the mean on axis = 0 for same col headers. But, I get an error using the round function on dataframe index type.

EDIT: based on the answers, I used

```
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns[0:], df.columns[0:]\
          .values.astype(float).round().astype(str))),inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(df.columns[0:], axis=1).mean()
```

And it messes up the column names as well as the values instead of giving me the mean based on col names...no idea why!

Comment: Yes? If you need clarification from an answer, please ask for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Use `groupby` along the 1st axis with a `lambda`.

```
df.set_index('TimeStamp', inplace=True)
df.groupby(by=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]), axis=1).mean()

                382       383
TimeStamp
10:28:00   0.012405  0.012405
10:30:00   0.012405  0.012422
10:32:00   0.055138  0.056121
10:34:00   0.055655  0.056802
10:36:00   0.055681  0.057086
```

Comment: This just splits it and doesn't round it!

Comment: the output here matches the desired output from the question. What are you looking for, if not that?

Comment: @Brain_overflowed It is completely identical to what you posted as your expected output. If something is wrong, you have to explain why. I'd recommend trying the answers first before writing them off...

Answer (score 6):

Rename columns with type conversion, move `TimeStamp` to index, and then use `groupby` to get column means:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: int(float(x)) if x!="TimeStamp" else x, inplace=True)
df.set_index("TimeStamp", inplace=True)

df
                382       382       383       383
TimeStamp                                        
10:28:00   0.012448  0.012362  0.012448  0.012362
10:30:00   0.012414  0.012396  0.012414  0.012431
10:32:00   0.055103  0.055172  0.055931  0.056310
10:34:00   0.055586  0.055725  0.056655  0.056948
10:36:00   0.055586  0.055776  0.056810  0.057362


df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).mean()

                382       383
TimeStamp                    
10:28:00   0.012405  0.012405
10:30:00   0.012405  0.012422
10:32:00   0.055138  0.056121
10:34:00   0.055655  0.056802
10:36:00   0.055681  0.057086
```

Answer (score 5):

with `np.floor` `rename` and `groupby`

```
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns[1:], np.floor(df.columns[1:].values.astype(float)).astype(str))),inplace=True)
df.set_index('TimeStamp').groupby(level=0,axis=1).mean().reset_index()
Out[171]: 
  TimeStamp     382.0     383.0
0  10:28:00  0.012405  0.012405
1  10:30:00  0.012405  0.012422
2  10:32:00  0.055138  0.056121
3  10:34:00  0.055655  0.056802
4  10:36:00  0.055681  0.057086
```

Comment: Sigh, it's the same thing with this user. Accepts my answer first, and then un-accepts.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i still prefer your solution ~ :-)

Comment: OPs are fickle beasts. They don't know what they want.

Comment: Sorry to get back to this again, but why would you reset the index at the end? The first line rounds it but the second line messes up the col names and the value...did not accomplish the goal :(

Comment: @Brain_overflowed I am reset the index cause I set_index before .

Comment: @Brain_overflowed and this is one year after question .. LOL

Comment: @Wen I know...sorry but I was newer to python and didn't know what I was doing. Now I am working on a different project and needed the same thing

Comment: The question is too old to have a bounty on it IMO. And the solution described works.

Answer (score 3):

Another method is via `pd.to_numeric`, just a slight variant of @coldspeed's answer i.e

```
df = df.set_index('TimeStamp')

df.groupby(pd.to_numeric(df.columns).astype(int),1).mean()

            382       383
TimeStamp                    
10:28:00   0.012405  0.012405
10:30:00   0.012405  0.012422
10:32:00   0.055138  0.056121
10:34:00   0.055655  0.056802
10:36:00   0.055681  0.057086
```

Comment: Uv'd sorry for the delay

Answer (score 3):

Generalised solution

```
df = pd.DataFrame({383.045:[1,2], 383.96:[3,4], 383.78:[5,5], 343:[9,11]})
df.columns = [int(i) for i in df.columns]
for i in set(df.columns):
    if len(df[i].shape) == 2:
        mean = df[i].T.sum()/float(df[i].shape[1])
        df = df.drop([i],1)
        df[i] = mean
```

Comment: why is this better?

Comment: I highly doubt it is. Please don't astroturf, you don't decide if your solution is better or not. Leave that to OP and the voters. Don't beg for upvotes either, that's bad form here.

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed, i will keep this thing in mind :)

Answer (score 2):

To round the column values to the nearest integer, you can group on a list comprehension that rounds each column (barring the first which is `TimeStamp`) to the nearest whole number and then takes the integer:

```
>>> (df
     .set_index('TimeStamp')
     .groupby([int(round(col, 0)) for col in df.columns[1:].astype(float)], axis=1)
     .mean())
                382       383       384
TimeStamp                              
10:28:00   0.012405  0.012448  0.012362
10:30:00   0.012405  0.012414  0.012431
10:32:00   0.055138  0.055931  0.056310
10:34:00   0.055655  0.056655  0.056948
10:36:00   0.055681  0.056810  0.057362
```